# AlertDialog not working properly on real device but on emulator

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

My AlertDialog is not showing `setpositive` button <kbd>yes</kbd> and `setnegative` button <kbd>no</kbd> in real device but showing in emulator. When I run the app on a real device it shows the alert dialog but not <kbd>yes</kbd> and <kbd>no</kbd> in real device. The app runs very well on the emulator. It works very well on the real device too but the buttons are not visible.

```
private void showAddFoodDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(FoodList.this);
    alertDialog.setTitle("Add new Food");
    alertDialog.setMessage("please fill full information");

    LayoutInflater inflater=this.getLayoutInflater();
    View add_menu_layout= inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_new_food_layout,null);

    edtName = (MaterialEditText) add_menu_layout.findViewById(R.id.edtName);
    edtDescription = (MaterialEditText) add_menu_layout.findViewById(R.id.edtDescription);
    edtPrice = (MaterialEditText) add_menu_layout.findViewById(R.id.edtPrice);
    edtDiscount = (MaterialEditText) add_menu_layout.findViewById(R.id.edtDiscount);
    btnSelect = (FButton) add_menu_layout.findViewById(R.id.btnSelect);
    btnUpload = (FButton) add_menu_layout.findViewById(R.id.btnUpload);

    //event for button
    btnSelect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            chooseImage(); //let user select image from gallery and save uri of  this image
        }
    });

    btnUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            uploadImage();
        }
    });
    alertDialog.setView(add_menu_layout);
    alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_shopping_cart_black_24dp);

    //set button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            //here ,just create new category
            if (newFood !=null)
            {
                foodList.push().setValue(newFood);
                Snackbar.make(rootLayout,"New category "+newFood.getName()+" was added",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: The most important skill you will ever learn is how to debug. https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0):

Create the alertDialog before showing it.

```
AlertDialog dialog = alertDialog.create();
dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the example to create proper dialog in android

```
  AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
  alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Are you sure,
     You wanted to make decision");
  alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("yes", 
     new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"You clicked yes 
           button",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
  });

  alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
     Override
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        finish();
     }
  });

  AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
  alertDialog.show();
}
```